# Forge Java SDK vs. Autodesk Client

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am not sure which maven package I should use:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.autodesk/forge-java-sdk (v1.0.3)

or

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.autodesk/com-autodesk-client (v1.0.1)

I know that the `com-autodesk-client` is a part of the `forge-java-sdk` project.

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-java-client.

However the maven package `com-autodesk-client` seems to be out of date (May 03, 2018)?

Comment: Sorry for letting you wait.  yes, com-autodesk-client  was a old version package, now it is forge-java-sdk. And this Maven package has not been updated for a while, I'd suggest you try with the source project of SDK https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-java-client , in which a few issues are fixed. you may build and produce a jar yourself, if we are not able to update Mave package soon. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang do you have an ETA for an upcoming release?

Comment: I hoped to get back to you with promising update, while the releasing may be depending on the team who will manage this. Please bear us with pushing this.